# Error loading D:\cygdrive\d\path\to\my\file.pdf

Tags: shell, pdf, emacs, cygwin, org-mode

In Cygwin Emacs 24.5.1, when exporting any Org file (using `C-c C-x C-e`), SumatraPDF gets open, but displays "Error loading D:\cygdrive\d\path\to\my\file.pdf".

To be clear, the PDF is correctly created on disk, but the path sent to the PDF viewer is wrong...

I'm using the same .emacs file from a Windows Emacs with no problem for exporting from Org to PDF.

Where should I look for finding out the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, but using cygwin path should be `\cygdrive\d\path\to\my\file.pdf`.. or not?

Comment: Cleary, `D:\cygdrive\d` is plain wrong. Now that I think about it, I guess SumatraPDF wouldn't grasp `\cygdrive\d` either... So, am I condamned to using Cygwin-only apps from Cygwin Emacs?

Comment: To be clear once again, I'm not building up the path to the file in any way... Somewhere, somehow, it gets badly constructed, or badly interpreted by SumatraPDF.